# Install plugin for IntelliJ from share folder

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, installation, software-distribution, intellij-plugin

I'm looking for a way to distribute my plugin in our local network. I don't want to share my plugin in the internet for everyone.

Is there is a way to share and install plugins from the IntelliJ via a share in my local network?
In the settings window, I found only 2 options: from the local disk and from the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing from a local network is not supported as far as I know. Your users can copy the plugin to a local directory and install it from there.

An alternative is to use [Enterprise Plugin Repository](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/03/enterprise-plugin-repository/):

> It is sometimes the case, you can create plugins you want to preserve for internal use only. With 
>   IntelliJ IDEA you can maintain your own enterprise repository to share your plugins with team members solely.